# Architecting/Designing a new Program

Tags: architecture, methodology

I had a, lets say, deficient program design/architecture class in undergrad and thus am really struggling on how to design programs given a problem*.  I was wondering if there was a set of resources (books, websites, etc) or problems(kind of like projecteuler.net)** or path to help me work on this deficiency.

I'm looking for resources/problems/etc to better learn design/architecture patterns within programming.

A great example: For my job, I have implemented an MVC framework in PHP(custom, because I want to learn).  I needed to bake User management into this framework and am just struggling with the implementation (I understand to use the $_SESSION var, I just want to user management to be modular and flexible like the rest).  **This post is not intended to solve my user management issue**.  *I know fixing the design issue will fix this naturally.*

I've looked around these here forums and haven't seen any great list of resources to draw off of.  If anyone has anything or point me to a post that I missed, feel free to point me there.  I really appreciate any insight/help/resource/etc that might be pointed out to me.

*I am familiar and can work with OOP/MVC frameworks, not completely proficient but I can do it
**ProjectEuler, where I am tends to be more functional than anything else.  I'm slowly working towards integrating OOP etc.  But my architecture skills in programming are terrible.

---

**tl;dr:**
I'm looking for resources/problems/etc to better learn design/architecture patterns within programming.

Comment: Not sure what the question is :S

Comment: I was almost closing it as off topic. but imho it's way to vague to fit at programmers SE. Ask about specific architecture problems or just google "design patterns". got a problem with a specific design pattern? Then tell what you don't understand with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the question is, but if you are only looking for some resources, there is this a good book for architectures - [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture by Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa), with some parts available [online.](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)

Than there are [GoF patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) summed up by Gamma.

[Software architecture in practice](http://books.google.cz/books?id=mdiIu8Kk1WMC&lpg=PP1&dq=software%20architectur%20in%20practice&pg=PR4#v=onepage&q&f=false) can be useful too.

Some basic intro to architectures is in [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/vit/ftp/pdf/intro_softarch.pdf), it's kinda old, but still valid...

Basically, GoF patterns, Enterprise patterns and [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29) are patterns you should be aware of...

Was this helpful?

Comment: This is helpful.  Thank you.  I understand the concepts of OOP/MVC and can even produce programs that utilize their functions.  I just struggle with designing them.  I could be merging functional parts (user management, error handling, etc) of OOP/MVC/GRASP, etc with the overall architecture and design (the OOP/MVC, etc).  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) and the Architecture sections of [Code Complete by Steve McConnell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670). I think those 2 are the best introductions to the concepts and then move into the other stuff.